# RecyclerView with multiple layouts, insert/delete function and click listener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing a job estimation app which stores information in a room database and holds a reference to it via a RecyclerView which user can use to access the data and make changes if needed.

I am retrieving a reference to the information using Live Data via a view model with Observer method inside a Fragment. This information is stored in a database when the user completes a form and presses the save button.

Currently I have developed two standard adapters, with different data sets and separate layouts.

```
public class HallDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HallDetailAdapter.myViewHolder> {
private List<HallDetails> mHallDetails;

public void setHallDetails(final List<HallDetails> hallDetails) {
    this.mHallDetails = hallDetails;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@NonNull
@Override
public HallDetailAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_design,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HallDetailAdapter.myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(mHallDetails != null){
        HallDetails details = mHallDetails.get(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(details.getName());
    }else{
        holder.mTextView.setText("No Data Entry");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mHallDetails != null)
        return mHallDetails.size();
    else return 0;
}
class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView mTextView;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class RoomDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomDetailsAdapter.myViewHolder> {

private List<RoomDetails> mRoomDetails;


public void setRoomDetails(final List<RoomDetails> roomDetails) {
    this.mRoomDetails = roomDetails;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RoomDetailsAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_design2,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RoomDetailsAdapter.myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(mRoomDetails != null) {
        RoomDetails details = mRoomDetails.get(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(details.getName());
    }else{
        holder.mTextView.setText("No data entry");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mRoomDetails != null){
        return mRoomDetails.size();
    }else return 0;
}
public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView mTextView;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_roomDetails);
    }
}
```

On change methods called inside Fragment:

```
 dataViewModel.getName().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<HallDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final List<HallDetails> hallDetails) {
            if(hallDetails != null) {
                hallDetailAdapter.setHallDetails(hallDetails);
            }
        }
    });

    dataViewModel.getGetName2().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<RoomDetails>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final List<RoomDetails> roomDetails) {
            if(roomDetails != null) {
                roomDetailsAdapter.setRoomDetails(roomDetails);
            }
        }
    });
```

My question is, how do I integrate multiple layouts to the RecyclerView while also adhering to these functionalities:

- Add and remove items from recycler view
- Have a click listener for each displayed item
- Show data inside corresponding layout which it has been referenced to inside adaptor, updated via Live Data.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**To Display Multiple Layout in Single RecyclerView, You have to use multiple viewholder in your recyclerview adapter class.**

For Example One view is use to **Display Your Data** and another view is use to **Display Admob/facebook Ad** between the data Item.So your Adapter Class look like Below Code.

```
public class StatusImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> images;
private String path;
private Context context;
OnIteamClickListner listner;
private String status;

private static final int AD_VIEW_HOLDER = 0;
private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_HOLDER = 1;

public StatusImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> images, String path, OnIteamClickListner listner, String status) {
    this.images = images;
    this.path = path;
    this.context = context;
    this.listner = listner;
    this.status = status;
}

public interface OnIteamClickListner {
    void onIteamClick(View view, String action, int position, String path);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position % Const.ITEMS_PER_AD == 0 && position>1)
        return AD_VIEW_HOLDER;
    return CONTENT_VIEW_HOLDER;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_HOLDER:

            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admob_banner_row_item, parent, false);
            return new AdViewHolder(itemView);
        case CONTENT_VIEW_HOLDER:
            // fall through
        default:
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
            return new ContentViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case AD_VIEW_HOLDER:
            AdViewHolder adViewHolder= (AdViewHolder) holder;
            adViewHolder.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CommonMethods.loadAd(context,adViewHolder.adView);
            break;
        case CONTENT_VIEW_HOLDER:
            ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder = (ContentViewHolder) holder;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( images.get(position));
            contentViewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            if (status.equals(Const.ONLINE)) {
                contentViewHolder.img_download.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_download_black);
            }
            if (status.equals(Const.OFLINE)) {
                contentViewHolder.img_download.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            contentViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onIteamClick(view, "View", position, path);
                }
            });
            contentViewHolder.img_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onIteamClick(view, "QuickView", position, path);

                }
            });
            contentViewHolder.img_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (status.equals(Const.ONLINE)) {
                        listner.onIteamClick(view, "Download", position, path);
                    }
                    if (status.equals(Const.OFLINE)) {
                        listner.onIteamClick(view, "Delete", position, path);
                    }

                }
            });

            contentViewHolder.img_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onIteamClick(view, "Share", position, path);

                }
            });
    }


}

private class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    AdView adView;

    public AdViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        adView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    }
}

private class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView img_share, img_download, img_view;

    public ContentViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusItem_imageView);
        img_share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_share);
        img_download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_download);
        img_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    }
}
```

}

**Call this adapter from your activity class file.**

```
StatusImageAdapter statusImageAdapter = new StatusImageAdapter(context, imageFiles, hiddenpath.getAbsolutePath(), this, Const.ONLINE);
```