# how to create custom adapter to use cardview for list view inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, retrofit2

i want to use card view inside my list view which is inside a fragment to show 2 variable, i already can connect to database and show only one variable "nama_matkul" from json into my list view, but i need to show "nama_matkul" and "sks" so i am creating a cardview but i am confused to make costum adapter for it

this is my json response

```
{
"error": false,
"matkul_mhs": [{
"nama_matkul": "matkul_3",
"sks": 3
}]}
```

this is my method inside fragment to initialize list view

```
 public void initListView1(){
        Call<MatkulMhs> getMatkulMhs = mApiService.getMatkulMhs(
                mPrefs.getUserID());
        getMatkulMhs.enqueue(new Callback<MatkulMhs>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MatkulMhs> call, Response<MatkulMhs> response) {
                boolean iserror_ = response.body().getError();
                if (iserror_ == false) {
                    List<Matkul_Mhs> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list = response.body().getMatkulMhs();
                    nama_matkul = new String[list.size()];
                    for (int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
                        nama_matkul[i] = list.get(i).getNamaMatkul();
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nama_matkul);
                    listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
```

this is my cardview (form_mhs_02_cardview.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_sqrwht"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_matkul"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mata Kuliah 1 "
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textStyle=""
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3 sks"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

i found this answer from another post but still confuse to change into my needs
,post can be found at [custom adapter for listview in fragment Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475996/custom-adapter-for-listview-in-fragment-android)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>
{
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> callLogData;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private View view;
    private Holder holder;
    private HashMap<String,String> hashMap;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.callLogData=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(resource, parent,false);

        holder=new Holder();
        holder.text_matkul=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_matkul);
        holder.text_sks=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sks);

        hashMap=callLogData.get(position);

        Date date=new Date(Long.parseLong(hashMap.get(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat=DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
        java.text.DateFormat timeformat=DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);


        holder.text_matkul.setText(hashMap.get(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        holder.text_sks.setText(timeformat.format(date));

        return view;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView text_matkul;
        TextView text_sks;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@togan-j-r please have a look at this example on this link https://medium.com/@Pang_Yao/android-fragment-use-recyclerview-cardview-4bc10beac446 and try to implement as per the demo example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> callLogData;
    private final Context context;
    private final int resource;

    /*
    This TODO code won't cause any issue even if not done.
    */
    //TODO : Check below comment
    private View view;

    //TODO :: NEED TO REMOVE as adapter handle multiple items therefore no meaning in having single field of holder object
    private Holder holder;
    //TODO :: NEED TO REMOVE same as above. you should get item from based on position provided in getView method no need to keep reference to it
    private HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        callLogData = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Added local instance of holder
        View view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        //Added local instance of holder
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.text_matkul = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_matkul);
        holder.text_sks = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sks);
        //Added local instance of holder
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = callLogData.get(position);

        //Commenting below code
        /*
                Date date=new Date(Long.parseLong(hashMap.get(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat=DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
                java.text.DateFormat timeformat=DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
        */


        holder.text_matkul.setText(hashMap.get("nama_matkul"));
        holder.text_sks.setText("sks");

        return view;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView text_matkul;
        TextView text_sks;
    }

}


public void initListView1() {
    Call<MatkulMhs> getMatkulMhs = mApiService.getMatkulMhs(
            mPrefs.getUserID());
    getMatkulMhs.enqueue(new Callback<MatkulMhs>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MatkulMhs> call, Response<MatkulMhs> response) {
            boolean iserror_ = response.body().getError();
            if (iserror_ == false) {
                List<Matkul_Mhs> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list = response.body().getMatkulMhs();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nama_matkul = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    item.put("nama_matkul", list.get(i).getNamaMatkul());
                    item.put("sks", list.get(i).getSKS());
                    nama_matkul.add(item);
                }
                //Note: layout resource changed to your card view and ArrayAdapter  to CustomAdapter
                CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.form_mhs_02_cardview, nama_matkul);
                listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error at CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.form_mhs_02_cardview, nama_matkul); required object java...java.lang.String>> found java...java.lang.String>[]

Comment: Modify HashMap object to ArrayList of HashMap objects, like this nama_matkul[i] = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); . This should solve the error above. As i can see from the code, in the adapter constructor you should pass an ArrayList not an Object.

Comment: This code is just modification of your original code. if you are interested in performance improvement than you may want to look for recyclerView and RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> or ListAdapter<ItemType,VH>(diffUtil.ItemCallback)

Comment: its didnt show anything , when i try to use log.d in method public View getView it didnt run

Answer (score 0):

**Use your Custom Adapter Class File Before SetAdapter.**

**CustomAdapter  adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nama_matkul);**

```
 public void initListView1(){
    Call<MatkulMhs> getMatkulMhs = mApiService.getMatkulMhs(
            mPrefs.getUserID());
    getMatkulMhs.enqueue(new Callback<MatkulMhs>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MatkulMhs> call, Response<MatkulMhs> response) {
            boolean iserror_ = response.body().getError();
            if (iserror_ == false) {
                List<Matkul_Mhs> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list = response.body().getMatkulMhs();
                nama_matkul = new String[list.size()];
                for (int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
                    nama_matkul[i] = list.get(i).getNamaMatkul();
                }
                CustomAdapter <String> adapter = new CustomAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nama_matkul);
                listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
```

Comment: the problem is my customAdapter is still wrong and i need to change it

Comment: Then i will suggest you to use Recycler view . For detail You can use below link at where i give answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717944/recyclerview-with-multiple-layouts-insert-delete-function-and-click-listener/58723545#58723545

or you can use github online cake shop project done by me. 
https://github.com/codeinsidecoffee/onlinecakeshopping/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mrlonewolfer/onlinecakeshopping/usermodule

at their in usermodule go fragment category i call adapter and in adapter class you can see my adapter class view.